# Authenticate phoenix query server by Knox

Tags: authentication, database-connection, apache-phoenix, knox-gateway, apache-knox

I have a phoenix query server run on port 8765. I can connect to it with out user or password. Now i need to perform authenticate from client to query server by using username and password. I found that knox can do that. Have anyone done it, please give me a guideline or other way to do.

I have set up knox and follow the guide i found on[https://knox.apache.org/books/knox-1-4-0/user-guide.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jdGZC.jpg)
My topology file
[File1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmH4F.jpg)

[File2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I6bVK.jpg)
[File3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvTHF.jpg)

Comment: What are you using for authentication? i.e. LDAP, PAM etc. You can use any of the authentication mechanism available in Knox https://knox.apache.org/books/knox-1-4-0/user-guide.html#Authentication

Comment: @SandeepMore i using ldap with config in file1 and file2 in the post but when i connect from dbeaver with jdbc url = jdbc:avatica:remote:url=https://ip_knox:8443/gateway/sandbox/avatica;avatica_user=sam;avatica_password=sam-password;authentication=BASIC. It return error in file3 in the post